# Right Linq syntax code?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I'm a newbie in Linq and C# and I'm going need some help. These following marks "***_*__*_***" need to be filled out with the right syntax word. The main problem is that I can't find the last keyword between `owner.OwnerID` and `dog.OwnerID`.

From your point of view, do you think that I'm using right synax code instead of "***_*___**"?

```
List<Owner> ownerList;
List<Dog> dogList;

    public class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int OwnerID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Owner
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int OwnerID { get;  set; }
    }



var query2 = _____ owner in ownerList
          _____ _____ dogList _____
 owner._____ _________ dog._____ into x
 select new { a = owner, b = x};



var query2 = from owner in ownerList
 from dog in dogList where
 owner.OwnerID _________ dog.OwnerID into x
 select new { a = owner, b = x};
```

Comment: Homework ? if so please put the appropriate tag...

Comment: Fill-in-the-blank programming! The best way to learn, of course.

Comment: I already tried it and get error message in every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query2 = from owner in ownerList
          join b in dogList on
 owner.OwnerId equals dog.OwnerId into x
 select new { a = owner, b = x};



var query2 = from owner in ownerList
 from dog in dogList where
 owner.OwnerID == dog.OwnerID into x
 select new { a = owner, b = x};
```

Actually the 2nd one doesn't really make any sense, and won't compile. But I can't think of anything else than `==` to put in the blank... It might be a mistake in the exercise

Comment: on a side note, why do we need the `into` here? this seems like an inner join, not a left outer join. couldn't you just do `select new { a = owner, b = dog }`?

Comment: I think that's a mistake in the exercise, `into` just doesn't fit here (in the 2nd query)...

Comment: I like your completion of the first one, except that I'm not sure that `join b in` maps neatly onto the two blanks originally between `ownerList` and `dogList`. I'm guessing that there's a missing blank in the first query?

Comment: yeah, i think the exercise here is "Write two different LINQ queries to retrieve a list of dogs and their relevant owners". i've honestly never used that second method (`where` instead of `join`). but then again, i rarely use the sql-like syntax altogether. lambda's ftw.

Comment: Thanks all guys for your support/advice!